# Pickle a custom class for multiprocessing python args=

Tags: python, multiprocessing

Hello I am trying to speed up my python programm through multiprocessing.

I have been following a few tutorials online about the subject but now that I want to try it myself I can't quite get it to work.

Please see my code below:

```
class Triplet():
    def __init__(self, code):
        self.code = code
        self.file1 = ""
        self.file2 = ""
        self.file3 = ""


    def join_three_files(self,triplet):
        self.file1 = File(self.path+triplet.file1)
        self.file2 = File(self.path+triplet.file2)
        self.file3 = File(self.path+triplet.file3)

        # open the workbooks
        self.file1.open()
        self.file2.open()
        self.file3.open()

        # read the files
        self.file1.read()
        self.file2.read()
        self.file3.read()

        # create a comon output file that every object writes to
        self.wbOut = xlsxwriter.Workbook(triplet.code+"-merged.xlsx")

        self.file1.write_workbook(self.wbOut)
        self.file2.write_workbook(self.wbOut)
        self.file3.write_workbook(self.wbOut)

        # close the excel file
        self.wbOut.close()

        self.loglist.insert(END,triplet.code+" completed")


    def join_all_triplets(self):
        stime = time.perf_counter()
        processes = []
        for triplet in self.well_formed:
            self.join_three_files(triplet)
            process = Process(target=self.join_three_files, args=(triplet,))
            processes.append(process)
            process.start()

        for process in processes:
            process.join()
            
        print(time.perf_counter() - stime)
```

which results in this error message:

```
 File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python38-32\lib\multiprocessing\reduction.py", line 60, in dump
    ForkingPickler(file, protocol).dump(obj)
TypeError: cannot pickle '_tkinter.tkapp' object
```

now I understand that pickling is the serialisation of a custom class to write it to a file but I am not really able to find a working example of how to use it with multiprocessing. Am I not supposed to pass the custom class as an argument? What am I missing here?

Comment: What is `self.well_formed`?  That appears to be where the unpicklable data is located.

Comment: You may also take a look at the [`dill`](https://github.com/uqfoundation/dill) project, if `pickle` doesn’t cut it.

Comment: I tried to keep to snippet as short as possible but self.well_formed is a list of "well formed" triplets.